# Fortran: is 0.d0 always == 0?

Tags: fortran, double, rounding, precision

In fortran, can I always count on 0.d0 == 0 to result in .true. ?
I.e.:

```
real(8) :: x
integer :: i

x = 0.d0
i = 0
write(*,*) x == i
```

I have tried in a simple piece of code and it turns out as .true. but can I always trust this?
The reason for this is I want to avoid problems with `acos(x)` if x < -1.

Answer (score 3):

`i` will be promoted to the floating point type *before* application of the relational equality test `==`.

A floating point zero will compare `true` with itself, and also with a negative signed zero.

"Can I always trust this?" Yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks, I take it that floating point 0 is 0 (not represented by 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000001 or similar)

Comment: No, zero can be represented exactly in floating point. This link might help you: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @ErikThysell The usual rule is that small integers can be represented exactly. Of course if you enter them directly, results of some computations can be inexact.

Comment: For an IEEE754 double precision floating point, "small" means anything up to the 53rd power of 2.